# Why is my container id empty when i press the command docker ps -a?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

docker ps shows no container id. when I type docker ps -a it shows that I exited 2 years ago, created 2 years ago, and again exited 2 years ago. how can I resolve this?

Comment: How about `docker service ls`? What is the ouput?

Comment: Please include the output you are seeing along with the command run, and if possible, some way to reproduce it. [mcve]